# Library with min-sdk 18 used in app with min-sdk 14

Tags: android, ibeacon

I'm developing Android app that among other things use iBeacons. I'm using [this](http://developer.radiusnetworks.com/ibeacon/android/) iBeacon library, with min-sdk 18.

What I'm trying to do, is to set min-sdk in my app to 14, but then I get:

```
Error:Main manifest has <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion='17'> but library uses minSdkVersion='18'
```

I'm aware that I can't use iBeacons on lower sdk than 18, nonetheless I want to be able to install this app - without iBeacons functionalities - on devices with lower sdk.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using the [Android iBeacon Library](http://developer.radiusnetworks.com/ibeacon/android/), no minSDK is required, and you can safely call most methods even on devices before Android 4.3, although doing so on older operating systems will do nothing but put a warning in LogCat.  See here: http://developer.radiusnetworks.com/ibeacon/android/backward-compatibility.html

For this to work, just be sure you are using the Android iBeacon Library version 0.7.6 or higher or the Pro version Android Proximity Library 1.1.2 or higher.

Generally you will want to check capabilities in code so you can appropriately message the user or make alternate functional arrangements using code like below.  But the API does not require that you do this.

```
public String getIncompatibilityReason(Context context) {
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 18) {
        return "requires Android 4.3";
    }
    if (!context.getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_BLUETOOTH_LE)) {
        return "requires Bluetooth LE";
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: So I've set minSdk to 9, and still have this error: [(...)/build/exploded-aar/com.radiusnetworks/AndroidIBeaconLibrary/0.7.4-3-g2397a87/AndroidManifest.xml:3] Main manifest has <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion='9'> but library uses minSdkVersion='18'. I'm using Android iBeacon Library version 0.7.6.

Comment: The error message suggests you are using an earlier library version "0.7.4-3-g2397‌​a87"  The latest version is available here:  http://s3.amazonaws.com/android-ibeacon-library.radiusnetworks.com/AndroidIBeaconLibrary-0.7.6.2.aar  Also, make sure you don't have two different versions of the library in the same lib directory, otherwise Gradle may pick the wrong one when building your project.

Comment: It was wierd because I never had any other version of this library. After cleaning project it works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Set the `minSdk` property of the library to 14 and check the SDK version before you use anything from the library.

Comment: But then i will have to check SDK version in this library also, am I right?

Comment: If you aren't calling any code from the library on devices below 18, you only have to modify the `AndroidManifest.xml`. You can look up the SDK version in your application and only call the library if it has 18 or higher.